# Dynamic accordion style checkbox menu in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, multi-select, optgroup

I want to create a select menu with dynamic accordion style checkbox options same as the picture below:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

My data looks like this:

```
 let allowedShifts = [{
    category: "Days",
    name: "D"
},
{
    category: "Evenings",
    name: "E"
},
{
    category: "Nights",
    name: "N"
},
{
    category: "Days",
    name: "d"
},
{
    category: "Nights",
    name: "n"
}];
```

I tried to implement the same using multiple select menu but was not able to pipe filter the data based on category. Here is my code for the reference:

HTML:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="shifts" id="exampleSelect2" [(ngModel)]="allowedShifts">
<optgroup label="Days">
    <option [value]="shiftIcon.name" *ngRepeat="let shiftIcon in allowedShifts | filter: {category: 'Days'}">
        {{shiftIcon.name}}
    </option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Evenings">
    <option [value]="shiftIcon.name" *ngFor="let shiftIcon in allowedShifts | filter: {category: 'Evenings'}">
        {{shiftIcon.name}}
    </option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Nights">
    <option [value]="shiftIcon.name" *ngFor="let shiftIcon in allowedShifts | filter: {category: 'Nights'}">
        {{shiftIcon.name}}
    </option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: is this angular or angularJS? what is *ngRepeat? It's either *ngFor for angular or ng-repeat for angularJS.

Comment: Sorry, I am new with Angular, I have used ngRepeat with pipe filters before with angularJS , so didn't knew it can't be used with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mix of Angular2 and AngularJS, they're different I bet you can tell from your edit. There is no ngRepeat nor filter pipe in Angular2, I would recommend altering the structure of your allowedShifts array, I dont know your use case so i can't suggest one.
Please read more about Angular, and the *ngFor specifically, use this [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) from the Angular team, will get you on track quickly.
For the multi select, as shown in the second picture, use [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview), pretty simple and does exactly what you want, also created by the Angular team.
Will take you a couple of hours if you're completely new, but it's worth the time.